# How to record a video with low frame rate in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I'm working on a project that needs to create GIF image by recording video and convert this video to GIF.
To do this, I follow 2 steps:

1. Convert video to list of images.
2. Convert list of images to GIF.

The question is: How can I record a video with its length about 10 seconds and its frame count about 20 frame. mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(framecount) doesn't work for some reasons.

```
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(GIFCamera.c); 

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        // mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AppConst.VIDEO_PATH);
        Camera.Size bestSize = GIFCamera.getBestSize();
        System.out.println(bestSize.width);
        System.out.println(bestSize.height);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
                .getSurface());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
```

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: check this please http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#QUALITY_LOW

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an alternative than an answer but why wouldn't you try taking a photo every 0.5 second instead of recording a video, if you want 2 frame/s ?

Comment: I hope I can do it because it saves lots of time. But the problem is : when taking a photo the screen turn into black in a short time for several devices and it will definitely make users uncomfortable.

Comment: I did not try to do it myself, but I think [LapseIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ui.LapseIt) does it this way and I didn't see any black screen appearing during the recording.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing unnecessary frames after you have recorded video. Might be easier.

Comment: I'm doing this way, but it takes lots of time. I really needs a better way. Thanks